# remote desktop connection for lan computers from wan ip

Tags: remote-desktop

so i have this xenserver running on my server machine which is running like 10 windows VM's which i need to get remote access connection to.
we have 1 static wan ip address that we want to use it to connect remotely to our virtual machines in this network.

this is the network build:

router ip: 10.1.1.1
xenserver machine: 10.1.1.2

VM 1 to 10: 10.1.1.50-60

i have forwarded remote desktop port to xenserver, but i dont know how can i get access to virtual machines through remote using wan ip...

Comment: Do you use a Firewall ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today must be the day for beginner questions.

You can't forward the same port (3389) from one public ip address to multiple virtual machines, each on their own private ip address. You'll need to change the RDP listening port on each virtual machine and then forward those ports from the single public ip address to the appropriate private ip address.

Comment: Instead of changing RDP listening port i would use port-forwarding at firewall side ! something like `publicip:3389 --> a.b.c.d:3389` `publicip:3390 --> e.f.g.h:3389` and so on, it will be a more centralized management and less work if you have 300 RDP servers in your Lan !